# call to getJSON in document ready failing silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two calls to getJSON in my document ready, both to populate different combo boxes on my page.  The first one works no problem.  The second doesn't populate the control, but I can see from my logs that it has requested the data from the model and the controller also gets the data.

```
        $.getJSON(
                    '<%= pathtomethod%>',
                    function(data) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(data); //converting to a javascript object vs. just string....
                      //  console.log(data);  
                        if (data !=null){
                                $.each(data, function(i) {
                                  $('#ruletypes')
                                         .append($("<option></option>")
                                         .attr("value",this.id)
                                         .text(this.name)); 
                            }); //end .each                             
                        }//end if
                    }//end function(data)
        );//end getJSON.        

        //populate rule conditions drop down box.
        $.getJSON(
                    '<%= pathtomethod%>',
                    function(data) {
                        data = $.parseJSON(data); //converting to a javascript object vs. just string....
                         console.log(data);
                        if (data != null) {
                        $.each(data, function(i) {
                            $('#rule_condition')
                                 .append($("<option></option>")
                                 .attr("value",this.id)
                                 .text(this.description)); 
                        }); //end .each
                    }//end if
                    }//end function(data)
        );//end getJSON.
```

There's no errors that appear in the console. but no data appears there either...
Here's the html for the rule_condition dropdown:

```
        <div class="first">
            <select id='rule_condition' name='rule_condition'>
            </select> 
        </div>
```

**EDIT 1**

I found the culprit.  The data being returned in the second request includes single quotes.  NOw I'm just googling to find out how to handle embdedded quotes in json data.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement the success and error functions and observe what the errors are.  Also, try using firebug

Comment: Ah, sorry - I saw that you edited the original post.  Question: what is the source of your JSON data?

Comment: a database... so I changed the data in the reference table i'm querying to not have any quotes embedded for now...